# using stored procedure to insert values in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MYSQL and I'm trying to use a stored procedure to insert values into a table.can someone help me with this please

```
 create procedure insertcust(in lname varchar(30), in fname varchar(30),dob1 date)

  begin

     insert into customer (lname,fname,dob) 
     values(lname,fname,dob1);//it is saying i have an incorrect syntax ere
   end
```

Comment: Davish : have you add delimeter in your procedure..?

Comment: no I haven't, I'm just trying to follow the basic knowledge I have from oracle and Microsoft sql to understand MYSQL

Comment: i think you are run your procedure in phpmyadmin right..?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your procedure directly in phpmyadmin then you should write something like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertcust`(IN `lname ` VARCHAR(30), IN `fname` VARCHAR(30), IN `dob1` DATE) 
           NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY 
DEFINER

insert into customer (lname,fname,dob)values(lname,fname,dob1)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks it did, but just for clarity with doing it how you showed just now?